# Can't reliably add two int arrays together when overloading sum operator on objects?

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to use the `operator+` function to add two objects together that contain `int` arrays. I am getting unreliable answers and I'm not sure why. Why are some of the members of my combined array getting strange `int` values?

Here is the function:

```
IntArray operator+(const IntArray& in1, const IntArray& in2){
    IntArray temp;

    for (int i = in1.low(); i <= in2.high(); i++){
        temp.iArray[i] = in1.iArray[i] + in2.iArray[i];
    }

    return temp;
}
```

and here is the output I am getting:

```
Sum of two arrays assigned to third array: IntArray a(1, 5);
                                           IntArray b(4, 8);
                                           IntArray c = a + b;

a[1] = 10 a[2] = 20 a[3] = 30 a[4] = 40 a[5] = 50` 
b[4] = 40 b[5] = 50 b[6] = 60 b[7] = 70 b[8] = 80`
Press any key to continue.

c[0] = 0 c[1] = 32777 c[2] = 100 c[3] = 38 c[4] = 80 c[5] = 100 c[6] = 60 c[7] = 74 c[8] = 80 c[9] = 32767 
Press any key to continue.
```

Am I missing something?

Edit: Adding the code for `IntArray`

```
class IntArray{
private:
    int *arrPtr;
    int iArray[SIZE];
    int arrLower, arrUpper;
    int size;
    string name;

public:
    IntArray();
    IntArray(int range);
    IntArray(int lower, int upper);
    IntArray(const IntArray& input);
    int high() const;
    int low() const;
    int compare(int in1, int in2) const;
    int operator==(const IntArray& in);  
    int operator!=(const IntArray& in);
    void setName(string input);
    IntArray& operator=(const IntArray& in);
    int& operator[] (int size)             {  return iArray[size];  }
    IntArray& operator+=( const IntArray& );
    friend IntArray operator+( const IntArray& in1, const IntArray& in2 );
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const IntArray& i);



};
```

and the constructor:

```
IntArray::IntArray(int lower, int upper){
    arrLower = lower;
    arrUpper = upper;
    // Creates array size
    size = arrUpper - arrLower + 1;
    operator[](size);

}
```

Here's a link to the whole program:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/fd4b8a5e1d1ac4d0982a

Comment: Please provide the code for `IntArray`.

Comment: @Pradhan Added. My apologies.

Comment: @Ryan: That's not enough. Post member function definitions. Constructors especially.

Comment: What did you try to achieve by calling `operator[](size)` at the end of constructor?

Comment: @Ryan Also, why didn't write your operator != in terms of operator==?  It could have been as simple as this: `return !(*this == in);`  Instead, you make `operator !=` go through the gauntlet of all of that code that attempts to turn operator== "inside out".

Comment: @Ryan To add what others have stated, you need to fix your class so that all of your members are initialized when you use IntArray.  This means that the entire `iArray` member must be initialized with values.  If you don't do that, then your entire copying of the objects using (copy constructor and assignment operator) is invalid.  It's faulty anyway, as you're supposed to copy the *entire* `iArray` from one object to another, not partially copy it as you're doing now in your assignment operator.

Answer (score 0):

While you haven't presented your implementation for `IntArray`, from the results, it looks like the culprit is your `for` loop. I am guessing your `IntArray` doesn't initialize values outside its `low` and `high` bounds. However, your `for` loop assumes that all values with index `>= in1.low()` make sense for `in2`. However, `b[0]` to `b[3]` would be uninitialized garbage. That is why `c[0]` to `c[3]` make no sense. An easy solution would be to change the implementation of `operator[]` to return an appropriate value(likely `0`) when the index is out of bounds.

EDIT : Looks like you want `operator[]` to be `non-const`, making it more natural. So, you could simply handle the out of bound cases appropriately in `operator+`. Alternatively, provide a `const at` function which does range checking and returns a dummy value if it is out of bounds.

Comment: Added a link to the whole program, I will double check the `operator[]` as well. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your addition operator adds array elements with indices from `in1.low()` to `in2.high()`, i.e. in your specific example this would be from 1 to 8. But you never initialize the values outside the respective range of either array. In each array values outside the range contain garbage. Hence the garbage in the results.

For example, `in1.iArray[1]` contains a meaningful value. But you never initialized `in2.iArray[1]`. `in2.iArray[1]` contains garbage. It is not surprising that `in1.iArray[1] + in2.iArray[1]` evaluates to garbage value that you see in the result.

The same is true for `in2.iArray[2]` and `in2.iArray[3]`. They too contain garbage.

The only meaningful additions your code makes are `in1.iArray[4] + in1.iArray[4]` and `in1.iArray[5] + in1.iArray[5]`. After that it adds garbage again, this time on `in1` side: `in1.iArray[6]`, `in1.iArray[7]` and `in1.iArray[8]` contain garbage.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing strange, you can easily infer the result if you check the below aligned version.

```
            a[1] = 10     a[2] = 20    a[3] = 30   **a[4] = 40 a[5] = 50** 
                                                   **b[4] = 40 b[5] = 50**  b[6] = 60 b[7] = 70 b[8] = 80
 c[0] = 0   c[1] = 32777  c[2] = 100   c[3] = 38   **c[4] = 80 c[5] = 100** c[6] = 60 c[7] = 74 c[8] = 80 c[9] = 32767
```